# How to create Gmail like edittext Layout

Tags: android

Need a layout like this layout
[image: I need layout like this, is there any google api for this layout]

Answer (score 4):

You have to add the style `style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"` to `TextInputLayout`

If you have moved away from the android support library and are currently using [Material Design Components](https://material.io/components/).

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/emailTextInputLayout"
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/edit_text_horizontal_margin"
    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/edit_text_horizontal_margin"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/edit_text_vertical_margin"
    android:hint="Username"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:id="@+id/emailTextInputEditText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

If not, I suggest you to read the article I have written on how to [migrate to Material Design Components](https://www.gsrikar.com/2019/01/migrate-to-material-components-mdc.html).

**Old Answer:**

**Eg:**

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/emailTextInputLayout"
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/edit_text_horizontal_margin"
    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/edit_text_horizontal_margin"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/edit_text_vertical_margin"
    android:hint="Username"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
        android:id="@+id/emailTextInputEditText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />

</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Comment: Use com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout instead of android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout in androidx.  Similarly, use com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText in place of android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText.

Answer (score 0):

Support New Library

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'
```